# TensorFlow deactivates Python when imported in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have installed TensorFlow with Miniconda 3 in the base environment and it works fine in the PyCharm editor. But when I try to use TensorFlow in a Jupyter Notebook, it crashes Python. This is what I see, even with a simple `import tensorflow as tf`, what could be the problem and how to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Could be a memory issue with your `Jupyter` editor.  I'd suggest, if you can, try importing only the appropriate modules required for your tensorflow application and see if that solves the issue.